# Fastest way to keep only first occurence of true; set rest to false

Tags: r, performance

My question is basically what the title says. Given some vector `x` consisting of both `TRUE` and `FALSE`, keep only the *first* occurrence of `TRUE` and set the rest to `FALSE`.

A small example:

```
smallExample <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
# Expected result:
# FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So far I have come up with 3 possible solutions.

```
matchFun <- function(x) {
    1:length(x) == match(TRUE, x)
}

whichFun <- function(x) {
    1:length(x) == which(x)[1]
}

vec_repl <- function(x) {
    {tmp <- rep(FALSE, length(x)); tmp[match(TRUE,x)] <- TRUE; tmp}
}
```

Testing these with the small example:

```
microbenchmark(
    `matchFun` = matchFun(smallExample),
    `whichFun` = whichFun(smallExample),
    `vec_repl` = vec_repl(smallExample),
    times = 500L
)

# Unit: nanoseconds
#      expr  min   lq   mean median   uq   max neval cld
#  matchFun  500  600  723.8    700  800  2100   500 a  
#  whichFun 1500 1700 1832.4   1800 1900 13500   500   c
#  vec_repl  700  800  919.2    900 1000  8400   500  b
```

However, the data I'm working with is much bigger, so I'm interested to see how it scales to larger vectors. The test above is probably not representative because with such small numbers overhead plays a substantive role. To this end, I've made a comparison by looping over multiple vector ranges (`n`) and using different ratios of `TRUE` and `FALSE` (`odds`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(microbenchmark)
library(plotly)

# The length of the vector to process
ns <- c(100, 1000, 10000, 20000, 40000, 60000, 80000, 100000)

# The ratio of TRUE/FALSE
odds <- c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1)
res <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(cross(list(ns, odds))))

# Add counter so we know where to store the result
t <- 1

# Loop over n's and odds, and save microbenchmarks in res
for(n in ns) {
    for(odd in odds) {
        bigExample <- runif(n = n) < odd
        mb <- microbenchmark(
            `matchFun` = matchFun(bigExample),
            `whichFun` = whichFun(bigExample),
            `vec_repl` = vec_repl(bigExample),
            times = 500L
        )
        mb <- summary(mb)
        mb$n <- n
        mb$ratio <- odd
        res[[t]] <- mb
        t <- t + 1
    }
}

# Combine all results
res <- bind_rows(res)

# Make a nice interactive 3D plot
plot_ly(data = res, x = ~ratio, y = ~n, z = ~median, color = ~expr, type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers")
```

[image: 3D scatterplot of microbenchmark results]

This relationship is also shown by the coefficients of a linear model using the length of the vector `n` as predictors of the `median` processing time (albeit small):

```
res %>% 
    group_by(expr) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(median ~ n, data = .x))) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    transmute(expr, beta = map_dbl(model, ~coefficients(.x)[[2]]))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   expr        beta
#   <fct>      <dbl>
# 1 matchFun 0.00193
# 2 whichFun 0.00332
# 3 vec_repl 0.00122
```

Now my question is, can you think of any other method that is faster than the ones I have come up with so far?

Comment: If speed is really an issue, this might be a good use-case for Rcpp

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with either Rcpp or C++ but I would love to learn! Any chance you can give me an example?

Comment: I was able to create an Rcpp example. My fist attempt was sub-optimal but I was able to tweak it to give a speed-up. I used the inline compiling R function `cppFunction`. It is also possible to create a stand-alone C++ file, compile it separately and then link. I don't know if that gives any further improvement or simply makes sourcing the R code quicker. The way I wrote it, the sourcing takes a few seconds as the C++ code is compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tweak of your `vec_repl()` gives a small speedup for larger examples:

```
vec_repl2 <- function(x) {
  {tmp <- logical(length(x)); tmp[match(TRUE,x)] <- TRUE; tmp}
}
```

For example:

```
bigExample <- c(logical(10000),TRUE,logical(10000))
microbenchmark(vec_repl(bigExample),vec_repl2(bigExample))
Unit: microseconds
                  expr    min     lq     mean median       uq      max neval
  vec_repl(bigExample) 34.204 47.428 157.2569 95.383 102.7885 6130.591   100
 vec_repl2(bigExample) 18.336 28.386 116.0537 78.282  85.6865 5439.463   100
```

Beyond that, you could perhaps look into [Rcpp](http://rcpp.org/).

**On Edit** Here is an Rcpp experiment:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('LogicalVector vec_repl3(LogicalVector x){
    int n = x.size();
    LogicalVector v(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(x[i]){
            v[i] = TRUE;
            return v;
        }
    }
    return v; //if you get here -- x had no TRUE to begin with
}')
```

Comparison:

```
microbenchmark(vec_repl(bigExample),vec_repl2(bigExample),vec_repl3(bigExample))
Unit: microseconds
                  expr    min      lq      mean median       uq     max neval
  vec_repl(bigExample) 69.113 70.8765 323.53679 76.166 167.3170 5882.35   100
 vec_repl2(bigExample) 33.499 36.6725 136.80877 38.084 135.4055 6405.28   100
 vec_repl3(bigExample) 31.031 33.3230  69.85751 35.263  80.3975 1836.78   100
```

As you can see, Rcpp provides a speed boost (in this case) but given that the resulting code would be harder to distribute, it might not be worth it. To really get a good feel for it, the benchmarking should probably involve a wider range of vector sizes as well as distributions of `TRUE` in those vectors.